# ¿Cómo creo un archivo en Nodejs y luego lo ejecuto en Linux?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy empezando a leer una guía de principiantes en node js. Pero no encuentro como crear un archivo y luego guardarlo. Según veo para ejecutarlo lo hago con el comando:

```
node nombredearchivo.js
```

Pero eso es solo para abrir, leí en otra parte que despues de escribir el código, escribiría esa mismo comando y se me guardaría mi codigo. Pero no me funciona...

Comment: Debes ir a la carpeta en la que se encuentra el archivo, por ejemplo con Windows se hace con el siguiente comando `cd C:\\carpetaArchivo\Archivo.js` y luego usas `node Archivo.js` para ejecutarlo.

Comment: Puedes ver un ejemplo detalado en esta página https://geekytheory.com/node-js-primeros-pasos-y-hola-mundo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crearte el archivo con cualquier editor de texto, hasta con el `Notepad` de windows, luego a través de consola, solo tendrías que ir a la ubicación del archivo y hacer el comando que has puesto en tu pregunta, con eso `node` ya ejecutaría el archivo.

Si tu instalaste node correctamente, desde la terminal y cualquier directorio, podrías hacer `node --version` , si te muestra la versión es que `node` esta bien instalado y podrás ejecutar el comando `node` desde cualquier directorio.

Imagina pues que creas un archivo en `/home/archivo.js` desde la terminal haces un `cd /home` y desde ahí solo tendrías que hacer `node archivo.js` de esta manera ya ejecutarías el archivo. Otra cuestion, es que se este ejecutando el archivo y como no pintas nada por pantalla de pienses que no se esta ejecutando, prueba a poner un `console.log('Hello')` en tu `archivo.js` y ver si te pinta algo por consola al ejecutarlo.

Comment: Pero lo puedo hacer desde la consola que me muestra node? y si no es posible, sabes como lo puedo hacer en Linux?

Answer (score 2):

En linux es igual que en los demas sistemas operativos, simplemente tienes que tener node instalado, editar el fichero, guardarlo y ejecutarlo:

```
~/test$ node --version
v6.12.3
~/test$ vi index.js
~/test$ cat index.js 
console.log("Hello NodeJS");
~/test$ node index.js 
Hello NodeJS
```